# C# Only Some Git Processes Execute

Tags: c#, git

I am trying to run a git command from my C# application. For some reason, the fetch as well as the pull command does not work (if I change the argument to tag it will tag the current branch). Currently I am pushing up a commit from the same repo at a different file location, running the process, but then using tortoise git shows the repo as still up to date when it should be behind.

Currently I am creating a process as such:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.FileName = @"path/to/git/executable/git.exe"
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.WorkingDirectory = "path/to/repo"
info.Arguments = "fetch";
Process fetchProcess = new Process();
fetchProcess.StartInfo = info;
fetchProcess.Start();
//output Standard Error and Standard Output here.
fetchProcess.WaitForExit();
fetchProcess.Close();
```

When I run the commands from shell it does work correctly.
Do processes not get the current checked out branch when they run git commands? I tried running "fetch --all" which errored so I'm not sure if running git processes has difficulties with branches.

Comment: Are you sure there is something 'new' to fetch? it may be running but if there is nothing new to fetch then it may look like it is not working

Comment: Should be as I push up a commit onto that branch from different file location, and after that fails, I'll then run a script that fetches and it will then be behind.

Comment: Check the resulting output by adding this line before you close: `string result = fetchProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` if it was successful it should be empty

Comment: fetchProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() is empty. However, on tortoise git it still shows that it is up to date, instead of behind. From tortoise git, if I then fetch all refs which calls "fetch --progress -v "origin"" it then shows it is behind (I have tried using fetch --progress -v "origin" for the argument as well.

Comment: I just used your code to do a pull and it worked fine. However before the updates showed up in my git gui I had to close and reopen. Try reopening tortoise git after running the c# code

Comment: @ivcubr It works now, I had the absolute path to the git.exe and when I changed it to just having the `gitInfo.FileName = "git.exe"` it worked. I'm not sure why the long file path worked for tagging and not fetching but there it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, having the full path to the git.exe was the problem. Once I made it simply `info.FileName = "git.exe"` I could fetch and pull. Bizarre that I was able to tag with the full git path but not do other commands but now it's fine.